# Combining a list of data frames into a new data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rows

This is a 3rd edit to the question (leaving below thread just in case):

The following code makes some sample data frames, selects those with "_areaX" in the title and makes a list of them. The goal is then to combine the data frames in the list into 1 data frame. It almost works...

```
Area1 <- 100
Area2 <- 200
Area3 <- 300
Zone <- 3

a1_areaX <- data.frame(Area1)
a2_areaX <- data.frame(Area2)
a3_areaX <- data.frame(Area3)
a_zoneX <- data.frame(Zone)

library(dplyr)   
pattern = "_areaX"
df_list <- mget(ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = pattern))
big_data = bind_rows(df_list, .id = "FileName")
```

The problem is the newly created data frame looks like this:

[image: newly created data frame]

And I need it to look like this:

| File Name | Area measurement |
| --- | --- |
| a1_areaX | 100 |
| a2_areaX | 200 |
| a3_areaX | 300 |

Below are my earlier attempts at asking this question. Edited from first version:

I have csv files imported into R Global Env that look like this (I'd share the actual file(s) but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this here):

[image: sample data frame]

They all have a name, the above one is called "s6_section_area". There are many of them (with different names) and I've put them all together into a list using this code:

```
pattern = "section_area"
section_area_list <- list(mget(grep(pattern,ls(globalenv()), value = TRUE), globalenv()))
```

Now I want a new data frame that looks like this, put together from the data frames in the above made list.

| File Name | Area measurement |
| --- | --- |
| a1_section_area | a number |
| a2_section_area | another number |
| many more | more numbers |

So, the first column should list the name of the original file and the second column the measurement provided in that file.

Hope this is clearer - Not sure how else to provide reproducible example without sharing the actual files (which doesn't seem to be an option).

addition to edit: Using this code

```
section_area_data <- bind_rows(section_area_list, .id = "FileName")
```

I get (it goes on and on to the right)

[image: new data frame]

I'm after a table that looks like the sample above, left column is file name with a list of file names going down. Right column is the measurement for that file name (taken from original file).

Comment: YOu may use `bind_rows(section_area_list, .id = "s5_section_area")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However "s5_section_area" is just the name of 1 of the files that is part of my big list. The names of the files in the list look as: "a1_section_area, a2_section_area...b1_section_area..." There are many of them. I would like the new data frame to have one column that lists all the file names (eg "a1_section_area...") and the next column to list the area measurement (provided by the original file).  Basically I measured the area of something and each measurement was saved in it's own cvs file. Now I want to combine all these into one big doc. Thanks

Comment: Please consider to provide a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Is there a way to attach files to this thread?

Comment: The `.id` create a column with the name whatever you apply and the values as the names of the `list`

Comment: Yes, there is def a new column called whatever is specified for ```.id```. However what I'm after is for that column to be populated with the names of files that make up the list. So, Column 1 lists the names of all the files that make up my list. Column 2 lists the area measurements (which come from the original file).

Comment: Sorry, not clear without a small reproducible example with expeceted output

Comment: I've edited the question from original version to hopefully something clearer? Not sure how else to make it clear without sharing files (which doesn't seem to be an option).

Comment: Based on the edit, I think the bind_rows with `.id` would do that i.e. `.id = "FileName"`

Comment: e.g. `lst1 <- list(a1_section_area = data.frame(Area = 7999), a2_section_area = data.frame(Area = 732));  bind_rows(lst1, .id = "FileName")#
         FileName Area
1 a1_section_area 7999
2 a2_section_area  732`

Comment: There are hundreds of csv files in the Global Env. I need to select a specific set (they all end in "_section_area"). Can't write each one out to make a new list. Need a fast way of combining them into a new data frame (each file is identical in appearance except the Area measurement varies). That's why I thought combine all csv files of interest into a list, then make a new data frame from that list.

Comment: Minor note: `mget` returns a `list`, and `ls()` has a `pattern` argument built in, so your `list(mget(grep(pattern,ls(globalenv()), value = TRUE), globalenv()))` can be shortened to `mget(ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = pattern))`. (And I'm a little concerned the extra `list()` will give you problems, as you don't have a list of data frames, you have a list containing a list of data frames.

Comment: And akrun isn't suggesting that you manually type all your data frames as a solution. He's trying to help you provide a small reproducible example so that we can actually test code we suggest to you. It'd be great if you'd **share code to define 2 or 3 small sample data frames (not as a picture - we can't test code on a picture of a data frame)**, along with the desired result corresponding to the sample input.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you! Yes, the list is much better now (it was list in a list before and looked wrong to me). Still not sure how to make a new data frame from that list though.

Comment: ```Area1 <- 100
Area2 <- 200
Area3 <- 300
Zone <- 3

a1_area <- data.frame(Area1)
a2_area <- data.frame(Area2)
a3_area <- data.frame(Area3)
a_zone <- data.frame(Zone)```  //Create some data frames. From the global environment, select only those with "_area" and make a list of those data frames. From that list, combine those data frames into 1 data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your list of dataframes (`df_list`) all the columns have different names (`Area1`, `Area2`, `Area3`) whereas in your output dataframe they all have been combined into one single column. So for that you need to change the different column names to the same one and bind the dataframes together.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

result <- map_df(df_list, ~.x %>% 
                  rename_with(~"Area", contains('Area')), .id = 'FileName')
result

#  FileName Area
#1 a1_areaX  100
#2 a2_areaX  200
#3 a3_areaX  300
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. This def worked for my sample data frames. However, still no luck getting the actual data to work. My list is populated with csv files, which were imported into R Global Env, if that makes a difference. And, the column names are actually all the same in the csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. In the end, I was able to combine the suggestions and some more thinking and came up with this, which works perfectly.

```
library("dplyr")                   
                  
pattern = "section_area"
section_area_list <- mget(ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = pattern))  
section_area_data <- bind_rows(section_area_list, .id = "FileName") %>%
    select(-V1)
```

So, a bunch of csv files were imported into R Global Env. A list of all files with a name ending in "section_area" was made. Those files were than bound into one big data frame, with the file names as one column and the value (area measurement in this case) in the other column (there was a pointless column in the original csv files called "V1" which I deleted).

This is what one of the many csv files looks like
[sample csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTlVx.png)

And this is the layout of the final data frame (it goes on for about 150 rows)
[final data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeYWi.png)